# Rodar uma aplicação Ruby on Rails localmente Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Tenho uma aplicação Ruby on Rails hospedada no Heroku. Ela tem um sistema de login na tela inicial que redireciona o cliente (no caso eu) para as demais funcionalidades da conta. Quando rodo ela localmente, (seja pelo `rails s` ou pelo `heroku local web`), abre o site principal, mas quando faço o login (com um usuário cadastrado localmente) ele nao vai para o "resto" do site, ele volta para a tela principal.

Uso Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Ruby 1.9.3-p551 e Rails 4.0.0

Comment: uso o sqlite3, mas nao tenho certeza se esta bem configurado rsrs ,sim eu tenho a pasta do projeto e executo a partir dela o rails s ou o heroku local web

Comment: Você usa sqlite3 no Heroku? 

Comment: creio que sim, nao fui eu que fiz esta parte do codigo

Comment: Veja se no Gemfile tem algum outro SGBD em ‘group :production’

Comment: mas resolvi o problema, usei rake db:reset ai funcionou

Comment: Ahhh, ótimo.. Posta como resposta pra alguém que tiver o mesmo problema :)

Comment: so estou com outra duvida, preciso implementar uma api, entao preciso fazer uma solicitacao URL mas nao sei se uso GET ou REST

Comment: Faz outra pergunta, aí fica mais fácil de ajudar

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264807/implementacao-de-api-nrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver, rodei

```
rake db:reset
```