# Implementação da API NRS Gateway

Tags: api, ruby, rest, get

Preciso implementar uma api da nrs gateway para envio de sms, para isso é necessario fazer uma solicitacao URL com os parametros necessarios, mas nao sei se uso GET ou REST para fazer isso, qual é recomedavel usar?

http://br.nrsgateway.com/http-api-pedido-envio-sms/

Comment: Tem esta opcao tambem na documentacao, GET REST SOAP, mas nao sei qual usar

Comment: Acho que seria uma questão de opinião. Pelo que li na documentação, eu preferiria REST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta para sua pergunta, na verdade, envolve um debate sobre as diferentes tecnologias de integração entre sistemas sobre o protocolo HTTP. GET, REST e SOAP são 3 destas tecnologias, todas suportadas por esse fornecedor.

GET costuma ser mais simples de implementar e testar. Você pode, por exemplo, simular rapidamente uma chamada diretamente da barra de navegação do seu browser e ter a resposta exibida no próprio browser. Os parâmetros são passados como em qualquer requisição, via URL, com ? e &. A tecnologia tem algumas restrições, como o tamanho dos dados passados como parâmetro na requisição. Mensagens SMS geralmente são curtas, então isso não deve ser um problema.

REST e SOAP são tecnologias mais robustas. Oferecem recursos mais avançados que, em aplicações mais complexas, se justificam a longo prazo. Por outro lado, exigem algum estudo maior e, dependendo do seu framework de desenvolvimento, podem também exigir o uso de bibliotecas de terceiros. Se prepare também, neste caso, para estudar outros protocolos acessórios, como JSON.

Fiz testes básicos com GET chamando o servidor NRS e funcionou bem rápido. Acho um bom caminho para começar.